# Dynamic sizing for divs

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a min-height only. However, when the contents in the div (a couple of more divs with text & images) start expanding in height, the div doesn't expand correspondingly.

Comment: Can we take a look at some of your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the div `height:auto` in the style.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the CSS property `overflow: auto;` to the containing `div`.

Some browsers will adjust a div's size to scale with the content inside of it automatically. Many don't.  Setting the overflow property to auto asks that the div expand to contain any content that overflows its original bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Ben L answer + if you have some float elements in that container, put

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

after last floating element. Also, you did not  tell us do you have some position:absolute elements? If you have, put position:relative on container.